# dotted navigation using Adobe Flex 3 or 4

Tags: apache-flex

I have a requirement of showing a pie chart with different data using 'dotted navigation'.
Below is a sample I need to implement similarly using Flex

< * * * * * >

If a user clicks left or right arrows, I need to show a pie chart with different data accordingly. 
Do we have any component like this in Adobe Flex?
Anyone have any suggestion how we can implement it using Adobe Flex 3 or 4?

Many Thanks
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard List or a Repeater. Make it the right size and set scrollPosition accordingly.